# Pinterest Pin It Button Code Breaks Website

Tags: wordpress, pinterest

I'm trying to use the Pinterest pin it button and it seems like every time I add the javascript into my page it breaks

```
<a data-pin-do="buttonBookmark" data-pin-custom="true" data-pin-round="true" href="https://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/"><img src="https://mysitehere.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Pinterest.png"/></a>

<script async defer src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<script>` tag isn't a void element, and therefore should ALWAYS be closed.

```
<script async defer src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
```

- Source @ https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_src.asp

---

### Learn more

- Empty elements @ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Empty_element